# Make Android sdcard read-only

Tags: android, filesystems

I need to test a scenario where the `sdcard` (or atleast a particular directory) is `read-only`. Does anyone know how I can do this on the emulator?

Basically I want to mount the sdcard as read-only. I tried the following command in `adb shell`, but it doesn't work.

```
mount -o remount r /sdcar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I managed to remount sdcard in read-only mode:

**Step 1.**
Execute `mount`  and see the list of mounted directories. Note the one with `/sdcard` or `/mnt/sdcard` in it.

On my Android 1.6 emulator:

```
/dev/block//vold/179:0 /sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,...
```

**Step 2.**

Execute next command:

```
mount -o remount,ro <block> <sdcard>
```

Where `<block>` and `<sdcard>` are first two items taken from `mount` output line with sdcard.

In my case the command would be:

```
mount -o remount,ro /dev/block//vold/179:0 /sdcard
```

Comment: The SD card is FAT32 formatted. This file system does not support file access rights, so `chmod` commands will not work there.

Comment: I've updated the answer with correct way of re-mounting the sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have set permissions in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```